# How to configure tilestache.cfg "projection"?

Tags: postgis, openlayers-2, mapnik, tilestache

I am using tilestache-1.51.6 and mapnik 3.0.9.
The tilestache.cfg is

```
{
  "cache":
  {
    "name": "Disk",
    "path": "/var/www/cachedata",
    "umask": "0000"
  },
  "layers":
  {
    "test":
    {
        "provider": {"name": "proxy", "provider": "OPENSTREETMAP"}
    },
    "kerala":
    {
        "provider": {"name": "mapnik", "mapfile": "district.xml"},
        "projection": "WGS84"
    }
  }
}
```

and the district.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!--<!DOCTYPE Map SYSTEM "mapnik3.dtd">-->
<Map background-color="#fff" srs="+proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" buffer-size="128" minimum-version="0.7.2">

<Style name="District_style_line">
<Rule>
     <MaxScaleDenominator>6600000000</MaxScaleDenominator> 
     <PolygonSymbolizer fill="#ebb1af"/>
         <LineSymbolizer stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="0.98" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</Rule>
</Style>
<Style name="District_style_text">
    <Rule>
    <MaxScaleDenominator>6600000</MaxScaleDenominator>
    <TextSymbolizer face-name="DejaVu Sans Bold" size="8" fill="black" wrap-width="10" avoid-edges="false" placement="interior">[name]</TextSymbolizer>
    <MinScaleDenominator>2000000</MinScaleDenominator>
    </Rule>
</Style>
<Layer name="District_Boundary" srs="+proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs">
    <StyleName>District_style_line</StyleName>
    <StyleName>District_style_text</StyleName>
     <Datasource>
        <Parameter name="dbname">testdb</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="extent">291627,904686,958569,1426831</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="geometry_field">the_geom</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="host">localhost</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="password">password</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="port">5432</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="srid">32643</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="table">(select * from district) as districts</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="type">postgis</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="user">test</Parameter>
    </Datasource>
</Layer> 
</Map>
```

I am not getting the tile properly, I think the projection is wrong.
What projection should I give ?